# Como pintar multiples rango de fechas en MonthCalendar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo las siguientes fechas para pintar dentro del MonthCalendar:

1. `2019-10-10` al `2019-10-13`
2. `2019-10-15` al `2019-10-18`
3. `2019-10-22` al `2019-10-27`

Mi codigo:

```
DateTime inicio1 = new DateTime(2019-10 -10); 
DateTime fin1 = new DateTime(2019-10-13); 
DateTime inicio2 = new DateTime(2019-10-15); 
DateTime fin2 = new DateTime(2019-10-18); 
DateTime inicio3 = new DateTime(2019-10 - 22); 
DateTime fin3= new DateTime(2019-10-27); 

calendario.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(inicio1, fin1); 
calendario.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(inicio2, fin2); 
calendario.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(inicio3, fin3);
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Tiene codigos o metodos que ha probado para resolverlo? Por favor puede añadirlos en la pregunta.

Comment: `DateTime inicio1 = new DateTime(2019-10 -10);
                DateTime fin1 = new DateTime(2019-10-13);
                DateTime inicio2 = new DateTime(2019-10-15);
                DateTime fin2 = new DateTime(2019-10-18);
                DateTime inicio3 = new DateTime(2019-10 - 22);
                DateTime fin3= new DateTime(2019-10-27);
                calendario.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(inicio1, fin1);
                calendario.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(inicio2, fin2);
                calendario.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(inicio3, fin3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene un error en las iniciaciones de cada `DateTime`.
Si quiere crear la fecha 10 Octubre 2019, la manera correcta a iniciar el `DateTime` es usar el **coma** entre los argumentos:

```
DateTime inicio1 = new DateTime(2019, 10, 10);
```

Si escribe `DateTime(2019-10-10)`, C# va a interpretar los argumentos como un expresion de sustraccion, y va a resolverlo como `DateTime(1999)`. Asi, no obtiene la fecha correcta.

---

La proriedad `SelectionRange` puede marcar solamente *un rango continuo*.
Si quiere marcar mas fechas, usa `BoldedDates`. Esta propriedad es un arreglo de `DateTime`, y asi tiene que almacenar todas las fechas en este arreglo una por una.

El codigo es:

```
DateTime[] fechasNegritas = 
    new System.DateTime[] {
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 10),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 11),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 12),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 13),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 15),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 16),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 17),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 18),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 22),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 23),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 24),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 25),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 26),
        new System.DateTime(2019, 10, 27)
    };


calendario.BoldedDates = fechasNegritas;
```

Comment: muchas gracias si funciona, y como podría agregar de manera dinámica desde una base de datos? estoy trabajando con reservaciones y tengo registrado tres rangos de fechas. distintas.

Comment: @juancito0101 Amigo, creo que debe crear una nueva pregunta por la problema que dice. En este sitio, cada una pregunta debe tener su propia problema especifica y no debemos discutir otra problema en esta publicacion. Quiere una metoda para _obtener tres rangos de fechas distintas desde una bbdd y almacenarlos en un arreglo_, pero este cuestion es sobre _selectar rangos de fechas en un MonthCalendar_. Si quiere, puede preguntarlo en una nueva publicacion. No te olvide para incluir los codigos que tiene. :)

Comment: @juancito0101 Y para este publicacion, si mi solucion te sirve, haz clic en la marca al lado de la respuesta (debajo del contador de puntos a favor o en contra) para marcar la respuesta como aceptada.